# removing a list of words from a dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a data frame made of data series containing strings.
I have a list of strings that I wish to be removed from each row.

```
tcl_list = ["tab", "cr", "lf", "doublequote", "singlequote", "eof"]
df[['Summary', 'Description']] = re.sub("|".join(tcl_list), ' ', df[['Summary', 'Description']])
```

For example:

From this:

```
the tab dog is acting sneaky like a doublequote cat doublequote
```

To this:

```
the dog is acting sneaky like a cat
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I have tried using the apply() and lambda functions but am unsuccessful. Any suggestions?

Comment: This usually happens when some of the values are not strings.  A quick way to check would be casting everything to String.

Comment: Try converting it to a raw string via `val = r'%s' % your_value`.

Comment: @cool_beans, is this solution works for your case ?

Answer (score 0):

i think regular expression needs to apply on individual string of column

```
df['val'] = ['the tab dog is acting sneaky like a doublequote cat doublequote']

df.val.apply(lambda x: re.sub("|".join(tcl_list),'',x))
```

**Or**

```
df.val.str.replace("|".join(tcl_list),'')
```

Out:

```
0    the  dog is acting sneaky like a  cat 
Name: val, dtype: object
```